# Source for text + audio books with normal search

Tags: electronic-resources, spanish

I would like to learn language by reading books in it and listen how native speaker narrator reads it. So I need normal source of audiobooks with the following properties:

1) provides both e-book and audio; text should be written with professional writer and readen by native speaking narrator (either no adaptations or ability to filter them out)

2) texts should not be short articles or posts, but full scale novels

3) allows exact search by language (for example including Espanol, excluding Catalan)

4) allows exact search by time of writing (for example including years 2000+ and excluding earlier)

5) allows to read abstract (better if it is in English)

6) the source can be free or not free

7) source should be suitable for PC or Android, not Kindle or something

---

Text and audio should be OF THE SAME books (the goal is language learning)

Answer (score 3):

[Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/browse/languages/es) satisfies most of your requirements (Spanish, ebook, audio, professional, novels, English options for many of the same books). Best of all, everything there is free.

Update: You can also try searching for "audiolibros". [Audible](https://www.audible.com/ep/Audible_en_Espanol) has a good collection of Spanish audiobooks, which of course have a corresponding book.

I highly doubt there is a Spanish book search engine with all your requirements, so your most realistic and productive option is searching audiobooks and then finding the corresponding physical/e-book.

Comment: Impossible to combine criteria (audio + text + date), also highly doubt there are modern books there since project contains public domain texts.

Comment: There are no any book satisfying criteria on the site.

Comment: @Dims I have updated my answer.